# CSV Import with multiple categories and commas in category names

Tags: category, import, csv

I have a CSV of products to import and each product has multiple categories, some with commas in the category name. To import a product and asign multiple categories, I would usually add a CSV column for _catagory and give a comma separated list of categories enclosed with double quotes:

```
sku,name,_category
1,Product 1,"Category 1,Category 2, Category 3"
```

However, if the category names have commas in them, how should I denote this in the CSV?

- Category, 1
- Category, 2
- Category, 3

Perhaps escape the comma in the category name?

```
sku,name, _category
1,Product 1,"Category\, 1,Category\, 2, Category\, 3"
```

Or perhaps the only way to do this is to use the category ID rather than the name?

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you import multiple categories. The correct way is to add a new line but without sku:

```
sku,name,_category
1,Product 1,Category1
,,Category2
,,Category3
```

As long as there is no new SKU, all lines belong to the same product.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/import-products-with-multiple-categories?rq=1

Comment: I'm not really familiar with the old dataflow import, I thought you were refereeing to the new import/export because the dataflow is deprecated since version 1.5. See [this](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/24762/4216) answer.

Comment: Thanks @Domeglic for your reply. I applied your instruction but it produces error.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2+, there is the field called **Multiple value separator** and **Fields enclosure**. If your category name contains comma(,) then **Multiple value separator** should be having the value of **"** and **Fields enclosure** should be enabled for the following scenarios:

```
"Default Category/test11/test12, test13/test14 & test15"
```

Then Magento creates the structure as follows,

```
+Default Category
++test11
+++test12, test13
++++test14 & test15
```

Comment: also refer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/203766/16046

Answer (score 0):

Both respondents misunderstood the question.
The solution is here: [Magento 2 csv product import : How to escape commas in category name](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/202945/magento-2-csv-product-import-how-to-escape-commas-in-category-name)

You have to change the Multiple value separator from comma (,) to something else like pipe (|) in the CSV and also in the settings at Import page in Magento. See the attached images below:

[image]

[image]