# How can i choose more than one category of product import using magmi

Tags: magento-1.9, magmi

How can i choose more than one category of product import using **magmi**

Comment: Hi Jeeva, please add to your question what versions of software you are using (Magento & Magmi). Please also describe what the steps are of what you're trying to do and what you hope to achieve. Right now, your question lacks details and this makes it a little vague...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import products with multiple categories](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/6074/import-products-with-multiple-categories)

Comment: Second answer in linked duplicate (by Alexey Shchur) applies to Magmi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can separate the category ids with commas:

```
websites    store_id    name                sku      price  category_ids
    w1          11      Daniel Pollera      GG1739   99.99  122, 182
    w1          11      Danhui Nai          FGG11556 99.99  122, 143
    w1          11      Danhui Nai          CGG11556 99.99  170, 174
```

Comment: shall i import category name instead of category id.