# Magmi Multi-Store Categories Import Error

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, category-products, magmi

I need to assign categories for my multistore,

CSV :

[image]

Store :

[image]

Magmi Error:

[image]

Comment: Can you please post error which you are facing ?

Comment: @Magento2Learner check my updated question.

Comment: "astroved " Try website code that shoud work for you.

Comment: Solved my self. Adding category_reset=0. Import CSV columns : sku,category_reset,categories

Comment: try this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/351208/82670